# Python: Class attribute which defaults to parent's value and is collectible for entire hierarchy

Tags: python, metaclass, class-attributes

This question is so hard to put in words. I hope the title captures it correctly.

What I am looking for:

```
class Parent():
    x = "P"

class ChildA(Parent):
    x = "A"

class ChildB(Parent):
    # not setting x
    pass
```

With this, the following should work exactly as seen:

```
>>> Parent.x
'P'
>>> ChildA.x
'A'
>>> ChildB.x
'P'
>>> ChildB.x = 'B'
>>> ChildB.x
'B'
```

Nothing special so far, but here is where it gets tricky, because the value of the parent's attribute should be preserved:

```
>>> ChildB.x = None
>>> ChildB.x
'P'
```

Also, I need this to work:

```
>>> ChildA.get_x_list()
['A', 'P']
>>> ChildB.get_x_list()
['P'] # 'P' only appears once
```

I read a lot about metaclasses recently and I figured this would best be done through the use of one:

```
has__attr = lambda obj, name: hasattr(obj, "_" + obj.__name__ + "__" + name)
get__attr = lambda obj, name: getattr(obj, "_" + obj.__name__ + "__" + name)
set__attr = lambda obj, name, value: setattr(obj, "_" + obj.__name__ + "__" + name, value)
del__attr = lambda obj, name: delattr(obj, "_" + obj.__name__ + "__" + name)

class Meta(type):
    the_parent_name = "mParent"

    def __new__(cls, class_name, bases, attributes):
        parent_attribute_id = "_" + class_name + "__" + cls.the_parent_name

        x = attributes.pop("x", None)
        if x:
            attributes["_" + class_name + "__x"] = x

        # build line of inheritance
        for b in bases:
            # find a base that has the parent attribute
            if has__attr(b, cls.the_parent_name):
                # set the parent attribute on this class
                attributes[parent_attribute_id] = b
                break
        else:
            # add the parent attribute to this class, making it an inheritance root
            attributes[parent_attribute_id] = None
        return super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, class_name, bases, attributes)

    def get_x_list(self):
        ls = [get__attr(self, "x")] if has__attr(self, "x") else []
        parent = get__attr(self, self.the_parent_name)
        if parent:
            ls.extend(parent.get_x_list())
        return ls

    @property    
    def x(self):
        if has__attr(self, "x"):
            return get__attr(self, "x")
        else:
            parent = get__attr(self, self.the_parent_name)
            if parent:
                return parent.x
            else:
                return None

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x:
            set__attr(self, "x", x)
        else:
            del__attr(self, "x")
```

While this already works exactly as expected, I was wondering whether using a metaclass is over the top and there is in fact a much easier way to do this?

**IMPORTANT:** I need this to be done in a way that absolutely NO special stuff is done in the derived classes. `x = "Q"` and `set_x("Q")` are acceptable. This is a requirement because I am designing an API, where `Parent` is part of the library and derived classes are out of my hands.

Bonus question: Is there a way to make the name ("x") of the attribute changeable in just one location? Meaning: Is it possible to create `get_x_list` and the `x` property through a string? I imagine something along the lines of:

```
attributes["get_" + attr_name + "_list"] = ...
```

But whenever I tried that, I got:

```
... missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a metaclass for either of those functionalities.

```
>>> ChildB.x = None
>>> ChildB.x
'P'
```

Just change the first line to `del ChildB.x` and this will work.

```
>>> ChildA.get_x_list()
['A', 'P']
>>> ChildB.get_x_list()
['P'] # 'P' only appears once
```

Try this:

```
(klass.__dict__['x'] for klass in ChildA.__mro__ if 'x' in klass.__dict__)
```

Change the outermost pair of parentheses to square brackets if you need a list instead of a generator.

Comment: @SheridanVespo: What should it do?  If it raises an `AttributeError`, you're violating the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and returning `None` arguably has the same problem.

Comment: When I tried it in the console before, it did not work. When I tried it just now, it did. I don't know what I did wrong. Forgive my already deleted comment, you were right.